# plotting vs. time and coloring the plot using another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

[this is an image of my data because I don't know how to upload the data][1]I have this data (the first 5 rows):

I want to plot the Speed at each time (24 hours) 5-min interval. and I want to use the Intensity as an intensity variable to add colors to the original plot.

I have searched for a solution but it seems that I am facing doubled problem here. First to plot all the 24 hours on a nice looking plot and how to color my speed points with the Intensity variable with ranged colors( four colors are fine to represent the intensity). 
Here what I have tried:

```
first 5 rows of "data" are:

Time    Speed   Intensity 
0:05    64      0.96624
0:10    65      0.46928
0:15    63      25.25
0:20    65      150
0:25    65      4.2382

My code is:

ggplot(data) + 
geom_point(aes(x=data$Time,y=data$Speed,color=factor(data$Intensity)),
size=5)

structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4/1/2015", 
"4/3/2015", "4/7/2015", "4/8/2015", "4/9/2015"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(1:20, .Label = c("0:00", "0:05", "0:10", 
    "0:15", "0:20", "0:25", "0:30", "0:35", "0:40", "0:45", "0:50", 
    "0:55", "1:00", "1:05", "1:10", "1:15", "1:20", "1:25", "1:30", 
    "1:35", "1:40", "1:45", "1:50", "1:55", "10:00", "10:05", 
    "10:10", "10:15", "10:20", "10:25", "10:30", "10:35", "10:40", 
    "10:45", "10:50", "10:55", "11:00", "11:05", "11:10", "11:15", 
    "11:20", "11:25", "11:30", "11:35", "11:40", "11:45", "11:50", 
    "11:55", "12:00", "12:05", "12:10", "12:15", "12:20", "12:25", 
    "12:30", "12:35", "12:40", "12:45", "12:50", "12:55", "13:00", 
    "13:05", "13:10", "13:15", "13:20", "13:25", "13:30", "13:35", 
    "13:40", "13:45", "13:50", "13:55", "14:00", "14:05", "14:10", 
    "14:15", "14:20", "14:25", "14:30", "14:35", "14:40", "14:45", 
    "14:50", "14:55", "15:00", "15:05", "15:10", "15:15", "15:20", 
    "15:25", "15:30", "15:35", "15:40", "15:45", "15:50", "15:55", 
    "16:00", "16:05", "16:10", "16:15", "16:20", "16:25", "16:30", 
    "16:35", "16:40", "16:45", "16:50", "16:55", "17:00", "17:05", 
    "17:10", "17:15", "17:20", "17:25", "17:30", "17:35", "17:40", 
    "17:45", "17:50", "17:55", "18:00", "18:05", "18:10", "18:15", 
    "18:20", "18:25", "18:30", "18:35", "18:40", "18:45", "18:50", 
    "18:55", "19:00", "19:05", "19:10", "19:15", "19:20", "19:25", 
    "19:30", "19:35", "19:40", "19:45", "19:50", "19:55", "2:00", 
    "2:05", "2:10", "2:15", "2:20", "2:25", "2:30", "2:35", "2:40", 
    "2:45", "2:50", "2:55", "20:00", "20:05", "20:10", "20:15", 
    "20:20", "20:25", "20:30", "20:35", "20:40", "20:45", "20:50", 
    "20:55", "21:00", "21:05", "21:10", "21:15", "21:20", "21:25", 
    "21:30", "21:35", "21:40", "21:45", "21:50", "21:55", "22:00", 
    "22:05", "22:10", "22:15", "22:20", "22:25", "22:30", "22:35", 
    "22:40", "22:45", "22:50", "22:55", "23:00", "23:05", "23:10", 
    "23:15", "23:20", "23:25", "23:30", "23:35", "23:40", "23:45", 
    "23:50", "23:55", "3:00", "3:05", "3:10", "3:15", "3:20", 
    "3:25", "3:30", "3:35", "3:40", "3:45", "3:50", "3:55", "4:00", 
    "4:05", "4:10", "4:15", "4:20", "4:25", "4:30", "4:35", "4:40", 
    "4:45", "4:50", "4:55", "5:00", "5:05", "5:10", "5:15", "5:20", 
    "5:25", "5:30", "5:35", "5:40", "5:45", "5:50", "5:55", "6:00", 
    "6:05", "6:10", "6:15", "6:20", "6:25", "6:30", "6:35", "6:40", 
    "6:45", "6:50", "6:55", "7:00", "7:05", "7:10", "7:15", "7:20", 
    "7:25", "7:30", "7:35", "7:40", "7:45", "7:50", "7:55", "8:00", 
    "8:05", "8:10", "8:15", "8:20", "8:25", "8:30", "8:35", "8:40", 
    "8:45", "8:50", "8:55", "9:00", "9:05", "9:10", "9:15", "9:20", 
    "9:25", "9:30", "9:35", "9:40", "9:45", "9:50", "9:55"), class = "factor"), 
    Speed = c(51L, 48L, 59L, 59L, 58L, 56L, 53L, 42L, 23L, 32L, 
    47L, 36L, 55L, 40L, 56L, 54L, 30L, 53L, 54L, 56L), Intensity = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How do you want to split the Intesity in four classes? Regarding the 24 Hours you probably have to transform it into a proper time-format. `dput(head(data, 20))` would be helpful. Further, in ggplot you should not use `data$` within the `aes`, it will look up the variables in the dataframe you provided in `ggplot(data)`.

Comment: Please do not post an image of your data, copy and paste `dput(head(data, 20))` in the question

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to relay your problem using built-in datasets or functions which can package your data in a copy/paste friendly manner.

Comment: Thanks Kath! I want the a range for each color ( like what the heat map does). Regarding the data I shall do this procedure, thank you again!

Comment: Thanks Roman! I tried to Exhibit my data for you guys, but, I think it still not professional. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your Date and Time into a proper datetime format and you can use a gradient scale for your Intensity:

```
## Transform Date and Time into a datetime
my_df$DateTime <- paste(my_df$Date, my_df$Time)
my_df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(my_df$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_df, aes(DateTime, Speed, color = Intensity)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  # Specify different gradient scale for your Intensity values (default is a sclae of blues)
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(4), breaks = c(0, 1, 4, 10)) +
  # Specify breaks and labels you'd like to have - optional!
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "5 mins", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

**Data**
I tweaked your data a little bit to show different Intesity values.

```
my_df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "4/1/2015", class = "factor"), 
                        Time = structure(1:20, .Label = c("0:00", "0:05", "0:10", "0:15", "0:20", "0:25", "0:30", "0:35", "0:40", "0:45", "0:50", "0:55", "1:00", "1:05", "1:10", "1:15", "1:20", "1:25", "1:30", "1:35"), class = "factor"), 
                        Speed = c(51L, 48L, 59L, 59L, 58L, 56L, 53L, 42L, 23L, 32L, 47L, 36L, 55L, 40L, 56L, 54L, 30L, 53L, 54L, 56L), 
                        Intensity = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @MustafaAttallah please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)